# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.8.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating my Android Studio to the latest version, I always get this problem. I don't know how to fix the problem.

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Can you post your gradle file? AFAIK there is no V 1.8.1 of the build-plugin

Comment: Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.8.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
}
dependencies {
}
apply plugin: 'announce'

Comment: Try using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` which is the newest version according to [Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)